# Do we need this whilst using input/button's in Twitter Boostrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For example, for all: `input:button`, `input:submit`, `button:button`, `button:submit`, we have these classes given by Twitter's Bootstrap:

- `disabled`
- `btn-disabled`

Then, we can disable those buttons using the HTML attribute like this:

- `<input type="button" disabled="disabled" />`, or
- `<button type="submit" disabled="disabled"></button>`

You can also use this pattern with Bootstrap:

- `<input type="button" class="btn btn-disabled" disabled="disabled" />`, or
- `<button type="submit" class="btn disabled"></button>`

With, or without the `disabled="disabled"` attribute, the button will appear as it is disabled, with any of the classes provided: `disabled` or `btn-disabled`.

So I actually have two question regarding this:

1. Why do **we** need these classes mixed with attributes?
2. How do you toggle (enable/disable) these using jQuery, whilst using Twitter's Bootstrap?

EDIT (my jQuery example for toggling the state of the button):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#disable').click(function() {
       $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       $('button').prop('disabled', true);
       $('button').addClass('btn-disabled');
       $('button').addClass('disabled');
    });

    $('a#enable').click(function() {
       $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
       $('button').prop('disabled', false);
       $('button').removeClass('btn-disabled');
       $('button').removeClass('disabled');
    });

    // Do we really need this just to disable/enable the button?
});
```

---

PS I know I can just use `disabled` in the attribute, but that's not my habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "real" buttons, such as `input:button` or `button`, you would use the attribute `disabled="disabled"`. No need for the `.disabled` class.

From what I can tell, the `.disabled` class exists so that you can make `a` tags that appear as buttons using the `.btn` classes also be disabled, so I would only use `.disabled` in that context.

And while I am not intimately familiar with every Bootstrap class, I see no mention of `.btn-disabled` in any part of the Bootstrap docs concerning buttons.

So, for inputs and buttons do this:

```
$('a#disable').click(function() {
   $('button').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

For `<a>`'s that look like buttons, do this:

```
$('a#disable').click(function() {
   $('a#myButton').addClass('disabled');
});
```

See [the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-disabled) for a pretty clear example of each case.

PS - You don't need to use both `.prop()` and `.attr()`, since they basically do the same thing. As long as you are using at least jQuery 1.6, `.prop()` is fine.

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't knew till now that there's no need for attr/removeAttr! Thanks alot! I was DRY-ing myself out with this! Cheers.